# I want to change color and text size in a script

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the color and the text size on w3schools.com
typewriter's example.
you find it here [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_typewriter)
So it is the "var txt" in the script that I am looking to change

How can I do that?

Comment: "*[You] find it here*" - and we should have been able to "find it" in your question. This question may well be a duplicate of those listed above, but even if it isn't the relevant code to reproduce your problem and/or your best attempt at a solution to that problem should be in your question. You don't get to just leave a link to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="demo" style="color: green"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

or add a style tag anywhere inside body like so

```
<style>
    #demo {
      color: red;
      font-size: 22px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the OP states doing this in a script rather than css or html style tag you would need to select the element to style and stating the colour and font size by do the following:

```
const selectElement = document.getElementById("demo").style;
selectElement.color = "red";
selectElement.fontSize = "x-large";
```

For the benefit of those coming across this post without having to follow the link this would be the full result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Typewriter</h1>

<button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

const selectElement = document.getElementById("demo").style;
selectElement.color = "red";
selectElement.fontSize = "x-large";
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```